# Change the description of an object on text-to-speech

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, text-to-speech, uiaccessibility

I'm currently working on providing accessibility to an app and I wanted to know if there's a way to change the description of a specific textField when you're marking/selecting it.

Say you have `myNumericInput: UITextField!` which you set to `NumberPad`. When voice over is activated and you tap on it, it will select it and say "text field". Is there a way to override this and have it say, for example, "numeric field"?

I know this is just the voice over app describing the object itself (textField), but maybe the description is confusing for the user, and I wanted to check if this can be better specified somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the value of `accessibilityHint` to your text field to better describe what it does.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615093-accessibilityhint)

Comment: You do not need to override `UITextField` to set the `accessibilityHint` of the text field.

Comment: @rmaddy gotcha, I improved the answer.